# Including .html file from parent dir fails to load .html assets

Tags: php, include, include-path, dirname

I'm  trying to include a .html into my .php file. I can do that, however assets defined relatively to the .html doesn't seem to load.

**I've tried with:**

```
include(dirname(dirname( __FILE__)) . '/html/index.html');
```

*PHP file structure:*

```
/misc/templates/template.php
```

*HTML file structure:*

```
/misc/html/index.html
```

Assets in the .html are loaded relative to the .html like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css" />
//= /misc/html/assets/css/custom.css
```

**How do I include/load the index.html in my template.php file having the index.html load it's relative assets?**

*ps. embedding purely with an html iframe is not an option*

*ps. serving the .html as .php is not an option*

Comment: Why you dont use .php for you html file? And your problem was gone.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that - for various reasons thats not an option either :) ... And even if I would rename index.html to index.php would that change anything? Assets would still not load with the above include?

Comment: Are you try write some text in your HTML file to see its your href link okej? I am try that on my server its work.

Comment: Text and HTML includes fine - however CSS/JS assets in that html is relative to the html file and are not loading

Comment: Can you provide path for "assets/css/custom.css"?

Comment: Already exists in the topic: /misc/html/assets/css/custom.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136538/discussion-between-online-telekom-and-user1231561).

Answer (score 0):

You need provide full url to your CSS file, because PHP cannot read your current addres.

Change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css" />
```

Change to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../html/assets/css/custom.css" />
```